# Find Thread Stack Size

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am just testing usage of pthread_attr_getstacksize() on 64 bit SLES linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#include <pthread.h>


void* doSomeThing(void *arg)
{
    unsigned long i = 0;
    pthread_t id = pthread_self();

    printf(">>> id = 0x%x\n", id);

    for(i=0; i<(0xFFFFFFFF);i++);

    return NULL;
}

main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pthread_attr_t      pattr;
    pthread_t           thread;

    int error = 0;
    size_t ssize=0;

    error = pthread_attr_init(&pattr);
    if(error)
        goto Return;

    error = pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&pattr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    if (error)
        goto Return;

    error = pthread_attr_getstacksize(&pattr , &ssize);
    printf(" >>> ssize = %u\n", ssize);

    error = pthread_create(&thread, &pattr, &doSomeThing, NULL);
    if(error != 0)
    {
        printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(error));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Thread created successfully\n");
    }

Return:
    return(0);

}
```

It gives me different stack sizes as 114500742, 2025756486, 4147952480 different times.
Why is the stack size varying?

Also ulimit -a shows

```
# ulimit -a
...
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 1635484
...
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
...
max user processes              (-u) 14942
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 1539280
```

Also when ulimit is showing stack size as 8 MB then why does pthread_attr_getstacksize() returns stack size in GBs?

The stack size is big and so I am not able to create beyond 186 threads as pthread_create fails with error 12( ENOMEM ).

Comment: Did you initialize `thread_attr`? Where do you call `pthread_attr_getstacksize`? Can you post an MVCE?

Comment: Sorry it is "pattr" and not "thread_attr". I call pthread_attr_getstacksize() just before pthread_create(). What does MVCE means?

Comment: MVCE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have modified the original question with a demo code.

Comment: The only problem I see is you should use `%zu` to print `ssize`. I can't reproduce the issue. What system you are on?

Answer (score 1):

> It gives me different stack sizes as 114500742, 2025756486, 4147952480 different times. Why is the stack size varying?

I think it is a bug in your OS.

From my previous experiments with variety of *nix systems (Solaris, AIX, HP-UX), Debian/Ubuntu, SLES10 and RHEL5, the default stack size (which you query and print) is stable and doesn't fluctuate between runs.

The only size variation which I have seen is related to 32bit vs 64bit builds of the same application. As expected, for 64bit applications the default thread stack size is bigger than for the 32bit applications.

> Also when ulimit is showing stack size as 8 MB then why does pthread_attr_getstacksize() returns stack size in GBs?

The `ulimit` shows the stack size for the main thread, not the thread stack size.

The main stack (used by thread where `main()` is called) is special, since it is created by kernel, allocated at the higher memory addresses and theoretically it can even *grow* up to the end of the heap (value returned by the `brk()`).

In contrast, the thread stack is allocated by application itself, and could be even allocated in the heap (though typically anonymous `mmap()` is used). It is not treated specially: it is a plain block of memory, however allocated, which would be freed by the application after the thread has terminated.

> The stack size is big and so I am not able to create beyond 186 threads as pthread_create fails with error 12( ENOMEM ).

- Report the problem to SUSE.
- Use the `pthread_attr_setstacksize()` to set the size explicitly in your application. Most *nix systems have default thread stack size around 256-512K, Solaris - 2MB, Ubuntu - 8MB. For many applications 512K is enough, but if your application puts large structures/arrays on the stack, then 8MB would be a safer value.